# Does "the hand's flat" refer to the palm only when the hand is open?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, phrase-usage

Does "**She slapped him with her hand's flat**" mean she slapped him with her palm or the back of her hand or either?

[image]

You can look at these pictures

[image]

[image]

Comment: We don't say 'the hand's flat', we use a fixed phrase, 'the flat of the hand' and yes, it's the palm side, with the fingers straight. She hit (or slapped) him with the flat of her hand.

Comment: In fact, to slap means to strike with the palm or flat of the hand or a flat object. You can just say she slapped his face.

Comment: The emphasis in "flat of the hand" is on contrasting it with a closed fist.

Comment: We also pat gently with the flat or palm of the hand.

Comment: Tom, where do you get these phrases from? I'm genuinely curious.

Comment: @FeliniusRex, I heard someone say "**hand's flat**" before.

Comment: @Tom Ok, thanks.

Comment: FWIW, I've never heard "the flat of the hand". Possibly a BrE thing?

Comment: @gotube - very common in the UK, and Merriam-Webster has it. The wrestlers in the Cornish style both wear tough jackets enabling them to gain better grip on their opponent. All holds are taken upon the other wrestler’s jacket, grabbing of the wrists or fingers is forbidden as well as any holding below the waist. Although all holds are to be taken upon the jacket, the flat of the hand is allowed to be used to push or deflect an opponent.